# Cisco STP issue with BIG IP F5 trunk

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, f5

[image]

We have above network and here is the cisco trunk configuration.

```
Nexus 5548

 interface Ethernet1/9
  description F5-10G-Link
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 201
```

Cisco 3850 (non-root switch)

```
interface Port-channel20
 description F5-2G-Etherchannel trunk
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 201
 switchport mode trunk
end

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/45
 description F5-1G-a
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 201
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol lacp
 channel-group 20 mode active
end

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/46
 description F5-1G-b
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 201
 switchport mode trunk
 channel-protocol lacp
 channel-group 20 mode active
end
```

links are up but if i check in STP configuration on cisco my 10G link is in blocking mode and 2G link is forwarding mode, as per STP cost calculation 10G link should be in forwarding because it has total cost to reach root is 4 and 2G link total cost to root is 5 right?

Even i tried to increase spanning-tree cost of 2G link but it didn't work still that link is in FWD mode.

```
SW2#sh spanning-tree int po20

Vlan                Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
VLAN0201            Desg FWD 3         128.2046 P2p      

Nexus#sh spanning-tree int e1/9

Vlan             Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
VLAN0201         Altn BLK 2         128.137  P2p
```

If i am trying to shutdown 2G trunk then on Nexus switch i am seeing following spanning-tree status which is weird

```
Nexus# sh spanning-tree int e1/9

Vlan             Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
VLAN0201         Desg BKN*2         128.137  P2p *LOOP_Inc
```

and this interface never come into forwarding state.

what i am doing wrong here? is my cisco config is wrong on trunk?

## EDIT

In f5 side we have default STP setting which is "Passthrough", Should i change it to RSTP?

Comment: Are you running CST or MST with the Big F5? PVST+ or Rapid-PVST+ is a Cisco propriety version of STP.

Comment: We are running `spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst`

Comment: The Big F5 needs an industry standard STP version. You are not allowing VLAN 1 on the trunks, and that is where the industry STP will send the BPDUs.

Comment: We have other F5 but not on these switch they are on different switch and they have no VLAN 1 in trunk configured and they are working so that is strange..

Comment: If it's not sending BPDU the how my link go in FWD and BLK mode ? How STP making 10G in BLK if doesn't passing BPDU

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your F5 is in passthrough mode, that means it is transparent to BPDUs -- The C3850 and Nexus switch see each other as directly connected STP neighbors.  So it makes sense that you can't block the 2G link.  To the switches, the 10G and 2G links are the same link.

You should adjust the cost on the link between the two C3850 switches so that that one is blocking.

Cisco rapid-pvst and RSTP (802.1w) are not compatible, so you should not configure RSTP on the F5.

Comment: What?? Why I should adjust cost between to c3850 trunk? It's in production also. Passthrough means that device is just dump and not doing anything right? If you see my question, why 2G link is fwd stat and 10G is in BLK ? And if I kill 2G link it's not getting failover to 10g link.

Comment: This is the post I found close to my issue https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/link-redundancy-on-cisco-switches

Comment: My STP failover putting 10G in loop guard mode and never recover, you can see in output in my question.

Comment: One more similar issue but unanswered https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11594246/cat-6509-stp-compatibility-issues-f5-ltm

Comment: Satish, passthrough means the F5 passes BPDUs.   It is as if the F5 is just a piece of wire.  So the Nexus sees the BPDUs from the C3850, and vice versa.  The 2G and the 10G links are logically the same link -- you can't shut only one down, because there is only one logical link.

Comment: the 10G link goes into loop guard mode because it stops seeing BPDUs from the C3850 and thinks there is a unidirectional link.  That's the way loopguard works.

Comment: Another option is to set both the Cisco switches and the F5 to MSTP (802.1s).  Then you can adjust the link costs.

Comment: How difficult it would be to set MSTP in production? I don't think it's good idea. Can I set RSTP on F5?

Comment: As I said, rapid-pvst and rstp are incompatible, so no.  Changing to MSTP will cause a momentary outage, so you will have to plan accordingly.

Comment: Stupid question, you said if I cut 2G cable in that case it will create unidirectional link , but how? If F5 is piece of wire then it shouldn't be a unidirectional link?? Right

Comment: No, I mean the Nexus stops seeing BPDUs, but the interface stays up.  So it assumes there's a unidirectional link, and shuts down.

Comment: Curious why and when people should use pvstp and mstp?

Comment: Pvstp is Cisco proprietary. Mstp is a standard